# JPA Portability Between MYSQL and MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, jpa, jpa-2.0

If I am using JPA with MongoDB and later if I would like to change database to MYSQL, how easy to do switch from MongoDB to MYSQL?

Reason why I am asking this because I understand that MongoDB is non relational and MYSQL is relational database. So at the time of changing database do I need to make lots of changes in Entity classes?

Comment: it depends on your JPA provider.

Comment: @dev If I am using Hibernate or EclipseLink, what would be the impact or implications?

Comment: not much familiar with EclipseLink. But as there are entities so I don't think switching will be that difficult.

Comment: @dev If I change the database type and other connect string informations specified in configuration files, does it suffices for switch from one database to another? Or will there be changes to be made in Entity classes?

Comment: @user75ponic: it actually depends on your ORM model as not all JPA features are supported by NoSQL paradigm. As an example here you can find EclipseLink's  [NoSQL mapping restrictions on JPA annotations](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/concepts/nosql003.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that must be said is that JPA was designed around RDBMS only, and so some aspects (e.g query language, joins) are not suited to "other types" of datastore. Consequently it is all down to how a particular implementation handles things.

I know that with DataNucleus JPA the impact is very small, in terms of configuration needed. Typically if an RDBMS-only configuration is seen when using MongoDB it simply ignores the setting, hence it is largely transparent.

Comment: Neil, So when there is a switch of database, JPA detects whether it is RDBMS or not and then ignores settings? Ideally when there is a switch there would be minimal changes is needed and that is one of fundamentals of JPA implementations isn't it?

Comment: "JPA" doesn't define anything since it is designed for RDBMS *only*. DataNucleus makes use of the "javax.persistence.jdbc.url" property and simply takes "mongodb:{server}/dbName" to say this is MongoDB, just like "jdbc:mysql:..." to say this is RDBMS (MySQL)